# Tornado: how to make it to catch changes done to JavaScript?

Tags: server, tornado

I'm trying to use Tornado and found that every time when I changed JavaScript or HTML files don't look changed.

I have an experience with Node.js and it worked well - if changes were not related with the server side everything updated itself.

How to solve this problem? Of course, I can stop the server every time but it's time-consuming and tedious.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your project folder where you tornado application is, you can listen for changes using the autoreload module. e.g

```
from os import walk
from socket import gethostname

from tornado import autoreload
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado.web import Application
from tornado.httpserver import HTTPServer
from tornado.web import RequestHandler
from tornado.options import define, options, parse_command_line

class TestHandler(RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("index.html")

class TestApplication(Application):
    def __init__(self, host=None, port=None):
        handlers = [
            (r"/", TestHandler)
        ]
        settings = {
            "autoreload": True,
            "compiled_template_cache": True,
            "debug": True,
            "static_path":  "static",
            "template_path":  "templates"
        }
        Application.__init__(self, handlers, **settings)
        self.host = host
        self.port = port

    def __call__(self):
        if self.port is None:
            define("port", default=8001, help="run on the given port", type=int)
        else: define("port", default=self.port, help="run on the given port", type=int)

        if self.host is None:
            define("host", default=gethostname(), help="run on host address", type=str)
        else: define("host", default=self.host, help="run on host address", type=str)

        parse_command_line()
        http_server = HTTPServer(self)
        try:
            http_server.listen(options.port, address=options.host)
        except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
            print("*!* keyboard interrupt detected...exiting.")
        except:
            print("*!* error occured...httpserver not listening.")
        else:
            print("*+* server listening on {host} {port}...".format(host=options.host, port=options.port))
            autoreload.start()
            for dir, _, files in walk('.'):
                [autoreload.watch(dir + '/' + f) for f in files if f.endswith("js") or f.endswith("css") or f.endswith("html")]


            IOLoop.current().start()
```

Then just call it and it will autoreload the server whenever you make changes to the files ending with the suffixes specified. i.e .js, .html, .css

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear from your question, but assuming you're serving your HTML and JS from Tornado's StaticFileHandler, you need to pass either `debug=True` or `static_hash_cache=False` to your `Application` constructor.